# Cannot find RadRails views in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aptana, radrails

I cannot see any of the RadRails views in my IDE. For example Rake tasks, rails console, generator view, etc..  See the screenshot for the available view options. 
I'm perplexed by the explanations I find on Aptana site and other forums. I cannot find a menu option called "My Aptana" or plug-ins anywhere. 
Also, the preferences window does not have the "Ruby" option as expected. See the screenshot.
I have the installed Aptana Studio on Mac (Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.0.1.201104291443) (http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download). [image: Available Views]

[image: Preferences]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aptana Studio 3 removed a number of the Ruby/Rails specific UI views. We took a "less is more" approach, since keeping the UIs up to date with the evolving ruby/Rails community and across versions proved to be very messy and in many cases the UIs were less productive than just using the command line.

The Rake tasks integration now uses a right-click menu on projects containing Rakefiles.
There are options to launch Rails apps under the server in run or debug mode as well. There's also project wizards for Ruby and Rails, and we have support for YAML, HAML, Ruby, Sass, SCSS, CSS, HTML and ERB files/editors.

For generators we urge users to use the command line inside the IDE (the Terminal view), or outside the IDE.

If there are specific views/functionality that you feel is missing and really needs to be brought back, feel free to add your voice/comments to http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-2416

Also see http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Rails+Development#RailsDevelopment-DeprecatedViewsServers%2CPlugins%2CGems%2CGenerators

Comment: Generator is so useful... BAD NEWS :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe Aptana Studio is all built around Rails you can find console under General and you can open a Terminal tab from Aptana folder. It's built a bit differently than RadRails

Comment: I can access the console. But how do I access the various views. I thought RadRails is included in Aptana Studio 3+ (as mentioned on their website). In any case, is there a different version that I should download that will have all the RadRails stuff?

Comment: I just use the Plain Aptana studio 3 installation. I'm not sure about different versions. Sorry I haven't used other views before as I just use Terminal for Rake tasks and generator. I noticed though there is a Command menu that has Ruby and Rails section. Try that it might be what you are looking for